# BEQS screen in Bloomberg ( excel API)

Tags: api, bloomberg

Can someone help me to write a code which do BEQS requests in VBA?
I use Bloomberg with R in general, but they haven't implemented the BEQS yet. And I have no idea on how to do this with VBA.

Thank you

Comment: Press Help Help (F1 key twice) and speak to the API team. They do have solutions or they will usually help you or guide you with a solution. Not sure what the trade off would be ;)

Comment: They dont help with API, already tried. They don't even give the password to existing templates they provide.

Comment: Well are you a paid customer? Do you have a terminal access? You could at least ask them what kind of solutions they have for `BEQS`. For templates, it was freely available for clients. Why don't you contact your account manager?

Comment: Yes I am. Well I did, they cannot give the password for the templates. And they don't help for API codes.

Comment: Things have surely changed alot lately... What about the DAPI guides on desktop API site?

Comment: Well Its not that straightforward...called a friend who wrote me a code, currently testing. WIll share here if it works.

Comment: If you try this kind of formula within Excel `d = eqs(c,'screen name','GLOBAL');`, it doesnt' work for BEQS?

Answer (score 1):

Please review EqsDataExample in DAPI SDK for how to send a BeqsRequest to //blp/refdata service, and how to parse the response.